# Ajax não envia o dado para outra página php

Tags: jquery, ajax

Não estou conseguindo enviar o valor de um input para outra página php.

Em minha página produtos.php eu faço uma busca no banco de dados e carrego a página mostrar_itens dentro de uma div. Ao carregar os dados dentro desta div, eu monto um input. Esse "input: deflarg" que eu não estou conseguindo enviar para o carrinho.php

parte do código...mostrar_itens.php

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td height="45">'."Definir a Largura da Porta: ".'<input type="text" name="deflarg" id="deflarg" size="5" maxlength="5"/>'. " cm".'</td>';
echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
//echo '<td height="45">' . '<input type="submit" name="comprar" value="COMPRAR"/>'.'</td>';
//echo '<td height="45">' . '<a href="carrinho.php?acao=add&id='.$linha["id"].'">Comprar</a>'.'</td>';

echo'<td height="45">' . '<a href="carrinho.php?acao=add&id='.$id.'">
    <img src="img/comprar-1.png" id="add_car" height="70" width="200" align="center" title="Adicionar ao Carrinho"></a>'.'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

Dentro da página mostra_item estou usando essa jquery + Ajax, porém sem sucesso.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add_car").click(function(e){ 
     if($("#deflarg").val()==""){ 
       alert("Ôpa!!!  " + "Você esqueceu de digitar a largura!");
       e.preventDefault();
     }
       $.ajax({
            url: 'carrinho.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('enviar_para_carrinho').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                  $('#deflarg').html(data);

            }
       });
   });
});          
</script>
```

Na página carrinho.php, estou fazendo assim:

```
<?php 

$largura = $_POST["deflarg"];
echo "Largura: " . $largura;

?>
```

Onde estou errando ?

Comment: Veja se o Ajax está lendo os dados antes do envio. Faz um console.log() desse `$('enviar_para_carrinho').serialize()` para ver se os dados estão lá.

Comment: Esse `$('.enviar_para_carrinho')` é a classe da tag `<form>`?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que, através do seletor:

```
$('enviar_para_carrinho')
```

Você está selecionando todos os elementos que possuem a **tag** `<enviar_para_carrinho>`. Desse modo, como provavelmente não existem esses elementos, você se enganou ao escolher esse seletor.

Se você quiser selecionar o elemento através de uma [classe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class), você deverá prefixar o seletor através de um ponto (`.`), indicando que você quer selecionar o elemento através do atributo `class`. Assim:

```
$('.enviar_para_carrinho').serialize()
```

Se, no entanto, você quiser usar o [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) do elemento para selecionar, você pode fazer assim:

```
$('#enviar_para_carrinho').serialize()
```

---

Para saber mais, queira consultar a [página de seletores](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) do jQuery.

Comment: Amigo explique o que você mudou no código, não precisava ter repostado tudo se você mudou apenas a seleção do form de `# `(id) pra classe `data: $('.enviar_para_carrinho').serialize(),`. Demorei pra perceber isso.

Comment: Realmente, obrigado pela observação, Bruno! :)  Quando escrevi a resposta original em 2017, ainda não estava muito acostumado com a forma como esse site funciona. Editei a resposta. ^-^

Comment: Caraca, que que essa pegunta tava fazendo na página inicial kkkk, nem vi que era de 2017 mano!!!